# How equation can be solved

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have equation $x^{t}(1-x)^{1-t}=a$. Is there any ideas how to solve this equation for x? It's looks like convolution, but I have no idea how to solve this. I realy need a help and ideas. Thank you!

Comment: If the $*$ means convolution, you can plug in the definition of convolution ... What do you get then?

Comment: @MattiP. sorry, it's multiplication, I edited my question.

Comment: What does $t$ represent?

Comment: In general, there is no way to solve for $x$ algebraically. However, it's possible to make comments for different values of $t$:
If $t$ is not a whole number, only $x>0$ is possible and the equation is still not always solvable. If $t$ is a whole number, there are two cases: an even $t$ does not cover all real values, and an odd $t$ does. So in short, only for odd integer $t$ there is always a (numerical) solution.

Comment: @MattiP, $t$ is real number, and less than 1, $x$ supposed to be real number and less than 1 too.

Comment: @Allawonder $t$ is real number, and less than 1, $x$ supposed to be real number and less than 1 too.

Comment: It's a good idea to graph the function
$$
y = x^t \left( 1 -x \right)^{1-t}
$$
for the value of $t$ which you desire and see what happens.

Comment: Great, that is much more helpful information. The equation may be written as $x^t=a+x$, so that the investigation of the root $x$ reduces to understanding how the power function $x^t$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and the line $x+a$ interrelate. The power functions are well understood, and for values of $t$ in the interval $(0,1)$, it is easy to see that $x^t$ is concave. With additional information that $0<x<1$ too, we have essentially solved the problem -- although not constructively or explicitly -- it should be obvious that no closed form solution exists.  Whether there is a solution depends upon the...

Comment: ...character of $a$, for if this parameter is positive, one cannot guarantee a solution, especially if $a>1$ since $x^t$ is $O(x)$ in this case. If $a=0$, there is a solution and if $a<0$, there may or may not be a solution in the domain given, especially when $a<-1$. If you have constraints on $a$ it would even be a nicer work.

Comment: **Edit:** There's a serious error in the foregoing. I was subconsciously working with $x\in[0,1]$ instead. So in fact if the interval were closed and $a=0$, one can show that there are exactly two solutions, namely at the endpoints. But since our interval here is open, no solution exists for $a=0$. For negative $a$, no solution exists too. Solutions exist only when $a$ is positive and less than $1/2$ (one can give a much tighter bound for $a$ -- but that only upon closer study).

Comment: As to actually finding these solutions, I think your only hope is numerical approximation, which can be guided qualitatively by what we know about the conditions for their existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider that we look for the zero's of function $$f(x)=x^{t}(1-x)^{1-t}-a\tag 1$$  for $0 < t <1$ and  $0 < x <1$.

The cases of $t=0$ and $t=1$ are trivial, as is the case of $t=\frac 12$ which gives $x_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2} \left(1\pm\sqrt{1-4 a^2}\right)$.

Its derivatives are
$$f'(x)=(1-x)^{-t} (t-x) x^{t-1}$$
$$f''(x)=(t-1) t (1-x)^{-t-1} x^{t-2}$$

The first derivative cancels when $x=t$ and
$$x=t\implies f(t)=(1-t)^{1-t} t^t-a\implies f''(t)=-(1-t)^{-t} t^{t-1}$$
$f''(t) <0 \, \, \forall t$ makes $f(t)$ to correspond to a maximum and then, since $f(0)=f(1)=-a$ , $(1)$ has two solutions if $a < (1-t)^{1-t} t^t$.

The solutions will be $$0 <x_1 < t \qquad \text{and}\qquad  t < x_2 < 1$$ To get estimates, the simplest we can do is to expand $f(x)$ as a Taylor series built at $x=t$
$$f(x)=\left((1-t)^{1-t} t^t-a\right)-\frac{1}{2} \left((1-t)^{-t} t^{t-1}\right)
   (x-t)^2+O\left((x-t)^3\right)$$ and, ignoring the higher order terms, this lead to the *estimates*
$$x_{\pm}^{est}=t\pm\sqrt{2} t^{-t} \sqrt{-t^{t+1} \left(a (1-t)^t+(t-1) t^t\right)}$$

Just to prevent the estimates to be outside the range $0 x < 1$, use
$$x_-^{est}=\max\left(\epsilon,t-\sqrt{2} t^{-t} \sqrt{-t^{t+1} \left(a (1-t)^t+(t-1) t^t\right)} \right)$$
$$x_+^{est}=\min\left(1-\epsilon,t+\sqrt{2} t^{-t} \sqrt{-t^{t+1} \left(a (1-t)^t+(t-1) t^t\right)} \right)$$
($\epsilon \approx 0.01$ for example) and use Newton method starting from these guesses. We could also systematically start using $x_-=\frac t2$ and $x_+=\frac{1-t}2$ if prefered

For illustration purposes, let us use $a=\frac 13$ and a few values of $t$.

- for $t=\frac 14$, we have $x_-=0.01$ and $x_+\approx 0.644531$. Starting from these values, Newton iterates would be 
  $$\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   n & x_-^{(n)}   & x_+^{(n)}  \\
   0 & 0.010000000 & 0.64453052 \\
   1 & 0.012560308 & 0.75596917 \\
   2 & 0.012831112 & 0.74517623 \\
   3 & 0.012833458 & 0.74505785 \\
   4 &             & 0.74505784
  \end{array}
  \right)$$ which are the solutions for eight significant figures.
- for $t=\frac 23$, we have $x_-\approx 0.261128$ and $x_+= 0.99$. Starting from these values, Newton iterates would be 
  $$\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   n & x_-^{(n)}   & x_+^{(n)} \\
   0 & 0.26112753 & 0.99000000 \\
   1 & 0.21474730 & 0.97292716 \\
   2 & 0.21755633 & 0.96169382 \\
   3 & 0.21756788 & 0.95983099 \\
   4 &            & 0.95979509 \\
   5 &            & 0.95979508
  \end{array}
  \right)$$  which are the solutions for eight significant figures.

  - for $t=\frac {11}{24}$, we have $x_-\approx 0.050096$ and $x_+\approx 0.866571$. Starting from these values, Newton iterates would be 
    $$\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
     n & x_-^{(n)}   & x_+^{(n)} \\
     0 & 0.05009570 & 0.86657097 \\
     1 & 0.09109635 & 0.84964479 \\
     2 & 0.10294484 & 0.84886276  \\
     3 & 0.10353862 & 0.84886124  \\
     4 & 0.10353996 &
    \end{array}
    \right)$$ which are the solutions for eight significant figures.

For sure, we could speed up the convergence replacing Newton by Halley of Householder methods but hte principle will remain the same.

**Edit**

It seems that the roots can be at least approximated by
$$x_-^{est}=a^{\frac{1}{t}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_+^{est}=1-a^{\frac{1}{1-t}}$$ For the worked examples, this would give $\{0.0123,0.7689\}$, $\{0.1925,0.9630\}$ and $\{0.0910,0.8684\}$ which seem to be more than acceptable.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! Your answer is very clear and helpful!

Comment: @DianaM. You are welcome ! If you thing it is good, may be, you could accept it in order other people know that this is a way to the solution. Cheers.